# Dynamic comparison of boxed primitive values

Tags: c#, object, primitive-types, boxing, icomparable

I need to generic compare two primitive (numeric!) types (both boxed as object) to find the greater one.
I can't use generics, because I only get objects, but I know the unboxed values are primitive numbers (int, short, long, float etc), so I can cast to IComparable.

How can I than compare those? CompareTo() throws an error because they are different types, but ChangeType can cause an OverflowException...?

```
        public static int Compare(object value1, object value2)
    {
        //e.g. value1 = (object)(int)1; value2 = (object)(float)2.0f
        if (value1 is IComparable && value2 is IComparable)
        {
            return (value1 as IComparable).CompareTo(value2);
            //throws exception bc value1.GetType() != value2.GetType()
        }
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the greater one"? I mean given the fact that they are all numeric I assume we are talking about numeric comparison right? Just needed to clarify

Comment: Yes, correct :) thanks for the reminder, I've added this info to the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe so

```
public static int Compare(object value1, object value2)
{
    if (value1 is double || value2 is double)
    {
        double d1 = Convert.ToDouble(value1);
        double d2 = Convert.ToDouble(value2);
        return d1.CompareTo(d2);
    }

    if (value1 is float || value2 is float)
    {
        float f1 = Convert.ToSingle(value1);
        float f2 = Convert.ToSingle(value2);
        return f1.CompareTo(f2);
    }

    long x1 = Convert.ToInt64(value1);
    long x2 = Convert.ToInt64(value2);
    return x1.CompareTo(x2);
}
```

The byte, short, int types can be converted to long without precision loss.

Comment: yes, this could be a sollution...but those types could be different...so there would be qzuite a lot of manual checks necessary ..
- is one double or float -> convert to double
- is one int, short, byte, sbyte, uint, ushort, lung -> convert to long
- is one ulong? -> ulong?
- is one decimal? -> ? 
...And than combinate every possiblity...(+ in some cases "<" comparison is not allowed)...
Thats why I was looking for a more generic approach...

Comment: ok, I think your sollution is still the best, as suggested here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.valuetype(v=vs.110).aspx Tank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way :

```
public void test() {

        Object o1 = 5465.0;
        Object o2 = 5465;
        Object o3 = 5465l;
        Object o4 = "5465";

        System.out.println(compare(o1, o2));
        System.out.println(compare(o1, o3));
        System.out.println(compare(o2, o3));
        System.out.println(compare(o3, o4));
}

public Double convertNumber(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Double) {
            return (Double) o;
        } else if (o instanceof Long) {
            return ((Long) o).doubleValue();
        } else if (o instanceof Integer) {
            return ((Integer) o).doubleValue();
        } else if (o instanceof String) {
            try {
                return Double.parseDouble((String) o);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        return null;
}

public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

        if (o1 == null && o2 == null)
            return 0;

        if (o1 == null || o2 == null)
            return -1;

        Double asNumber1 = convertNumber(o1);
        if (asNumber1 == null)
            return String.valueOf(o1).compareTo(String.valueOf(o2));

        Double asNumber2 = convertNumber(o2);
        return asNumber2 == null ? -1 : asNumber1.compareTo(asNumber2);


    }
```